# The driving voltage has tailing phenomenon after stopping the PWM signal

Tags: mosfet

[image]

[image]

When it enters the protection state, it stops sending out the PWM signal. At this time, the auxiliary discharge MOSFET cannot be turned on, and the driving voltage is still at a high level. How can I solve this problem? We hope that Vgs will be lower than 1.5V when the PWM signal is stopped。

Comment: You haven't told us what voltage you are measuring nor where it is on your extremely blurred image.

Comment: You need a rapid gate discharge during Mosfet off state via some low resistance path, something about Rgate <100ohm. So use less Rg or transistor driver for high speed switching..

Comment: Please provide a schematic with sharper resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to time the disable of the PWM so that the output finishes in the low state after discharging the gate drive.

The resistors you have on the gates will then ensure that the output FETs stay off.
Your image of the schematic is too low a resolution to read the values of the resistors but they may need to be lower in value if it takes many milliseconds to discharge.